# Jquery more details of a table row object in a popup

Tags: jquery, html, popup

I have been working on popup forms which provide additional details of an object when the corresponding row is clicked from a table of objects.

I have loaded a list of items into a list of objects called `elements`. I am displaying the elements as shown below. Each object contains attributes value1, value2, value3, value4 and value5.

```
<div id="tableId" class="tab-content">
    <table id="filteredList">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Value 1</th>
                <td>Value 2</th>
                <td>Value 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            #foreach ($element in $elements)
            <tr class="popupOpen" data-href="#entry1">
                <td>$!{element.value1}</td>
                <td>$!{element.value2}</td>
                <td>$!{element.value2}</td>
            </tr>
            #end
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div id="entry1" class="largWin">
        <div id="choice">
            <div id="issued" >
                $!{element.value4}
                $!{element.value5}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div align="center">
            <a href="#" class="btn">Back</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am using the following to display a popup on click of each row.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr.popupOpen').click(function () {
        var popup = $(this).attr('data-href');
        $(popup).fadeIn(100);
        $(popup).css({
            'margin-top': '20px',
            'margin-left': '40px'
        });
        $('div.tab-content').append('<div id="mask"></div>');

        $('#mask').fadeIn(100);
        return false;
    });

    $('a.btn, #mask').on('click', function () {
        $('#mask , .largWin').fadeOut(100, function () {
            $('#mask').remove();
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

As you can see from above, I am displaying values 1,2,3 in the table and I need to display values 4 and 5 in the popup. But I am not able to take the data corresponding to the current clicked `element` to the popup.

Is there a way to get the whole data (**not just values 1,2,3 but the whole object**) of the clicked row to the popup so that I could display value4 and value5?

Comment: Can you make a fiddle?

Comment: @thomas In fiddle, is there a way to load the object data?

Comment: just include a small sample of it on the first line: `var dataObj = [{"name1": "value1"}, {"name2": "value2"};` Then use it in your template.